# Casting to primitive type and using as parameter?

Tags: c#, casting, primitive-types

I'm trying to compile a project containing this method;

```
public void Send<T>(object o) where T : struct {
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    bw.Write((T)o);
}
```

I inspired from this method (working);

```
public static T Cast<T>(object o) {
    return (T)o;
}
```

BinaryWriter.Write function supports primitive types for parameters, so I thought I could use it like that. However, Visual Studio says "*The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(bool)' has some invalid arguments*"

I'm trying to avoid writing a long switch statement containing every primitive type and add a parameter to method for choosing the type. This is ugly and doesn't seem right.

This is simple and elegant:

- Send< int>(123);
- Send< bool>(true);

But why isn't it working? And what is the right way to do it?

Comment: what are you trying to acomplish with that, are you familiar with [serialization concept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.71).aspx), maybe that's a different approach you can try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload resolution is performed at *compile time*. So the compiler's trying to find a method with a parameter which will be valid *whatever type `T` is, (within its constraints, which don't help here). It can't find such a method. Given that the only constraint is that `T` must be a struct, the *only* non-generic parameter type that would be valid would be `object` (via boxing).

If your aim was to use whichever overload was appropriate based on the *execution-time* type of the object, you'll need to either use dynamic typing, like this:

```
public void Send(dynamic d) {
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    bw.Write(d);
}
```

... or fetch and execute the right overload with reflection (which is sort of what dynamic typing would do).

Comment: I am not familiar with "dynamic" keyword but it seems working :) I will read about it, thank you.